# cakephp: is there a way to get relationship from $this->Session->read('Auth');?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

```
$user = $this->Session->read('Auth');
```

produces the following array:

```
array(
    'User' => array(
        'id' => '2',
        'email' => 'info@trinoweb.com',
        'username' => 'trino',
        'created' => '2012-10-11 12:41:52',
        'modified' => '2012-10-11 12:41:52',
        'last_online' => null,
        'main_image' => null,
        'address' => null
    )
)
```

I want it to produce the same thing but with all the joins/relationships... like so...

```
array(
    'User' => array(
        'password' => '*****',
        'id' => '128',
        'email' => '12312@asdas.com',
        'username' => 'teresa',
        'created' => '2012-10-11 12:41:52',
        'modified' => '2012-10-11 12:41:52',
        'last_online' => null,
        'main_image' => null,
        'address' => null
    ),
    'Inbox' => array(),
    'Sender' => array(),
    'Upload' => array()
)
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not unless you write it in there when the Auth key is populated. This is a session variable, not a dynamic lookup on the models.

You will need to basically modify the login methods to do a lookup on these relationships and populate the Session data then.

Bear in mind, that this will be STATIC data. If you change a relationship, that will not be reflected in this array. You will need to update this array when that happens, and then it's going to get messy.

Comment: As of Cake 2.2+ (maybe 2.3+, can't remember for sure) AuthComponent supports `contain` key. Although, like you mentioned, it will only grab the data when the user logs in and won't update automatically.